# Retrieving a BLOB with System.Data.SQLite and C#

Tags: c#, sqlite, ado.net, system.data.sqlite

I'm newbie in *SQLITE* and I'm currently using **System.Data.SQLite.dll** version **1.0.89.0** in a **C#** project.
My database contains a simple table **'files'** with following columns:

- [id] **VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL**
- [chunk] **INTEGER NOT NULL**
- [content] **BLOB NOT NULL**
- [size] **INTEGER NOT NULL**
- [date_ins] **DATETIME NOT NULL**

**PRIMARY KEY**(id,chunk)

I created a class (**OfflineStorage**) to add and retrieve files in this table as *BLOBS*.
**Save** method works ok, but **Load** generate an **InvalidCastException** on **GetStream** extended method.

```cs
public class OfflineStorage
{

    private static string l_strConnectionTemplate = "Data Source={0};Version=3;Password=\"{1}\";";

    private string l_strConnection;
    private int SQLITE_MAX_BLOB_LENGTH;

    private string l_strCreateTable = @"CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS [files]" +
                                       "( " +
                                       "     [id] VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, " +
                                       "     [chunk] INTEGER NOT NULL, " +
                                       "     [content] BLOB NOT NULL, " +
                                       "     [size] INTEGER NOT NULL, " +
                                       "     [date_ins] DATETIME NOT NULL, " +
                                       "     PRIMARY KEY(id,chunk) " +
                                       ")";

    private string l_strSelectQuery = @"SELECT chunk, content, size FROM files WHERE id = @id ORDER BY chunk";
    private string l_strUpdateQuery = @"UPDATE files SET content = content || @new_content, size = size + @size WHERE id = @id AND chunk = @chunk";
    private string l_strInsertQuery = @"INSERT INTO files(id, chunk, content, size, date_ins) VALUES(@id, @chunk, @new_content, @size, DATETIME('now'))";

    public OfflineStorage(string strFilename, string strPassword = "")
    {
        SQLiteConnection l_objConnection = null;
        if (!File.Exists(strFilename))
        {
            l_strConnection = string.Format(l_strConnectionTemplate, strFilename, "");
            SQLiteConnection.CreateFile(strFilename);
            l_objConnection = new SQLiteConnection(l_strConnection);
            l_objConnection.SetPassword(strPassword);
            l_objConnection.Close();
        }

        l_strConnection = string.Format(l_strConnectionTemplate, strFilename, strPassword);
        l_objConnection = getConnection();
        using (SQLiteCommand l_objCommand = new SQLiteCommand(l_strCreateTable, l_objConnection))
        {
            l_objCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        SQLITE_MAX_BLOB_LENGTH = 1000000;

        CloseConnection(l_objConnection);
    }

    private SQLiteConnection getConnection()
    {
        SQLiteConnection l_objConnection = null;

        try
        {
            l_objConnection = new SQLiteConnection(l_strConnection);
            l_objConnection.Open();
            return l_objConnection;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            CloseConnection(l_objConnection);

            throw new OfflineStorageException("Local Service open db error.", ex);
        }
    }

    private void CloseConnection(SQLiteConnection objConnection)
    {
        if (objConnection != null)
        {
            objConnection.Close();
            objConnection = null;
        }
    }

    public long Load(string strID, Stream objStream)
    {
        if (!objStream.CanWrite)
            throw new NotSupportedException("Stream not writable.");

        SQLiteConnection l_objConnection = getConnection();

        // Columns Identifier (name of file)
        SQLiteParameter l_objID = new SQLiteParameter("@id", DbType.String);
        l_objID.Value = strID;

        SQLiteCommand l_objCommand = new SQLiteCommand(l_strSelectQuery, l_objConnection);
        l_objCommand.Parameters.Add(l_objID);

        // Load File Records
        SQLiteDataReader l_objReader;
        try
        {
            l_objReader = l_objCommand.ExecuteReader();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            CloseConnection(l_objConnection);
            throw new OfflineStorageException("SQLite exception.", ex);
        }

        long l_lFileLength = 0;     // Complete file length
        int  l_iDBChunk = -1;       // Current chunk on database
        int  l_iChunk = 0;          // Current 'sub chunk'
        long l_lChunkLength = -1;   // Current 'sub chunk' length

        try
        {
            // For each record of current file selected by identifier
            while (l_objReader.Read())
            {
                l_iDBChunk = l_objReader.GetInt32(0);       // Chunk ID
                l_lChunkLength = l_objReader.GetInt64(2);   // Chunk size 
                Trace.Assert(l_iChunk == l_iDBChunk);       // Compare expected Chunck with Database ID Chunk
                l_lFileLength += l_objReader.GetStream(objStream, 1, l_lChunkLength); // Load chunk
                l_iChunk++;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            string l_strMessage = string.Format("SQLite exception on file {0}, DB chunk {1}: \n{2}", strID, l_iDBChunk, ex.Message);
            throw new OfflineStorageException(l_strMessage, ex);
        }
        finally
        {
            l_objReader.Close();
            l_objCommand.Dispose();
            CloseConnection(l_objConnection);
        }

        if (l_iChunk < 1)
        {
            string l_strMessage = string.Format("File {0} not readed on db.", strID);
            throw new OfflineStorageException(l_strMessage);
        }

        return l_lFileLength;
    }

    public void Save(string strID, Stream objStream, bool bOverwrite = false)
    {
        const int CHUNK_SIZE = 8 * 1024;

        if (!objStream.CanRead)
            throw new NotSupportedException("Stream not readable.");
        long l_lOldPosition = objStream.Position;

        SQLiteConnection l_objConnection = getConnection();
        byte[] lar_byBuffer = new byte[CHUNK_SIZE];

        SQLiteParameter l_objID = new SQLiteParameter("@id", DbType.String);
        l_objID.Value = strID;
        SQLiteParameter l_objContent = new SQLiteParameter("@new_content", DbType.Binary);
        l_objContent.Value = lar_byBuffer;
        SQLiteParameter l_objChunk = new SQLiteParameter("@chunk", DbType.Int32);
        SQLiteParameter l_objSize = new SQLiteParameter("@size", DbType.Int32);

        SQLiteCommand l_objCommand = new SQLiteCommand(l_strInsertQuery, l_objConnection);
        l_objCommand.Parameters.Add(l_objID);
        l_objCommand.Parameters.Add(l_objContent);
        l_objCommand.Parameters.Add(l_objChunk);
        l_objCommand.Parameters.Add(l_objSize);

        int  l_iReturn, l_lBytesRead;
        int  l_iChunk = 0;          // Current 'sub chunk'
        int  l_iDBChunk = 0;        // Current chunk on database
        long l_lDBChunkLength = 0;  // Current length of chunk
        l_objChunk.Value = l_iDBChunk;

        //Transaction
        using (SQLiteTransaction l_objTransaction = l_objConnection.BeginTransaction())
        {
            // Read File from stream
            while ((l_lBytesRead = objStream.Read(lar_byBuffer, 0, lar_byBuffer.Length)) > 0)
            {
                // Check for next Chunk
                if ((l_lDBChunkLength + l_lBytesRead) >= SQLITE_MAX_BLOB_LENGTH)
                {
                    l_objCommand.CommandText = l_strInsertQuery;
                    l_iChunk = 0;       // reset 'sub chunk' counter
                    l_lDBChunkLength = 0; // reset chunk size
                    l_iDBChunk++;       // increase chunk ID
                    l_objChunk.Value = l_iDBChunk;
                }

                l_lDBChunkLength += l_lBytesRead;   // Increase length of chunk
                l_objContent.Size = l_lBytesRead;   // Length of Content field
                l_objSize.Value = l_lBytesRead;     // Chunk lenght (write on 'size' column)

                #region WRITE
                try
                {
                    l_iReturn = l_objCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    if (l_iChunk == 0)
                    {
                        l_objCommand.CommandText = l_strUpdateQuery;
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    l_objTransaction.Rollback();
                    CloseConnection(l_objConnection);
                    string l_strMessage = string.Format("SQLite exception on file {0}, DB chunk {1}, chunk {2}: \n{3}", strID, l_iDBChunk, l_iChunk, ex.Message);
                    throw new OfflineStorageException(l_strMessage, ex);
                }

                if (l_iReturn != 1)
                {
                    l_objTransaction.Rollback();
                    CloseConnection(l_objConnection);
                    string l_strMessage = string.Format("DB chunk {1}, chunk {2} of file {0} not inserted on db.", strID, l_iDBChunk, l_iChunk);
                    throw new OfflineStorageException(l_strMessage);
                }
                #endregion WRITE

                l_iChunk++;
            }

            l_objTransaction.Commit();
        }
        l_objCommand.Dispose();
        CloseConnection(l_objConnection);
        objStream.Position = l_lOldPosition;
    }
}
```

DB Data Reader Extended class:

```cs
public static class DbDataReaderExtension
{
    public static long GetStream(this DbDataReader objReader, System.IO.Stream objStream, int iIndex = 0, long lFileLength = -1)
    {
        const int CHUNK_SIZE = 7 * 1024;

        byte[] lar_byBuffer = new byte[CHUNK_SIZE]; // Buffer
        long l_lBytesRead;          // Bytes readed from SQLite database column
        long l_lFieldOffset = 0;    // Field offset on database column
        long l_lBytesRemainig = lFileLength;

        while ((l_lBytesRead = objReader.GetBytes(iIndex, l_lFieldOffset, lar_byBuffer, 0, lar_byBuffer.Length)) > 0)
        {
            l_lFieldOffset += l_lBytesRead; // prepare next offset

            if (l_lBytesRemainig > 0)       // check if a FileLength was set
            {
                l_lBytesRemainig -= l_lBytesRead; // remove readed bytes
                if (l_lBytesRemainig < 0) // Cut last bytes not valid if file is bigger than column size
                    l_lBytesRead += l_lBytesRemainig;
            }

            // write only valid bytes 
            objStream.Write(lar_byBuffer, 0, (int)l_lBytesRead);
        }

        return lFileLength < 0 ? l_lFieldOffset : lFileLength;
    }
}
```

I found this exception is generated because ReadBytes method (SQLiteDataReader) call VerifyType

```cs
private TypeAffinity VerifyType(int i, DbType typ)
{
  CheckClosed();
  CheckValidRow();

  TypeAffinity affinity = GetSQLiteType(i).Affinity;

  switch (affinity)
  {
    ...        
    case TypeAffinity.Text:
      if (typ == DbType.SByte) return affinity;
      if (typ == DbType.String) return affinity;
      if (typ == DbType.SByte) return affinity;
      if (typ == DbType.Guid) return affinity;
      if (typ == DbType.DateTime) return affinity;
      if (typ == DbType.Decimal) return affinity;
      break;
    case TypeAffinity.Blob:
      ...
  }

  throw new InvalidCastException();
}
```

In this function isn't expected that typ is equal to ***DbType.Binary*** and *affinity* is equal to  ***TypeAffinity.Text***.
Can anyone help me to understand this problem?
Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ok, here's how i have added and retrieved blobs.

i suppose it all depends on whether the byte[] is a manageable size. This worked for small objects being serialized to the database.

use GetDataTable to get the data and then on the row in question extract the byte array with the following:

```
    public byte[] getByteArray(DataRow row, int offset)
    {
        object blob = row[offset];
        if (blob == null) return null;
        byte[] arData = (byte[])blob;
        return arData;
    }
```

this is how i add them:

```
    private System.Object syncLock = new System.Object();

    public int ExecuteNonQueryWithBlob(string sql, string blobFieldName, byte[] blob)
    {
        lock (syncLock)
        {
            try
            {
                using (var c = new SQLiteConnection(dbConnection))
                {
                    using (var cmd = new SQLiteCommand(sql, c))
                    {
                        cmd.Connection.Open();
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@" + blobFieldName, blob);
                        return cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
                return 0;
            }
        }
    }

    public DataTable GetDataTable(string sql)
    {
        lock (syncLock)
        {
            try
            {
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                using (var c = new SQLiteConnection(dbConnection))
                {
                    c.Open();
                    using (SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand(sql, c))
                    {
                        using (SQLiteDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                        {
                            dt.Load(rdr);
                            return dt;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion about using DataTable, and it works ok! Thank you!